# Having had some one to do

Tags: difference, to-infinitive

Please look at the following

> Having advised many of your colleagues (yet having had no one stand up for me when the shit hit the fan)...

and

> Having advised many of your colleagues (yet having had no one ***to*** support me when I faced adversity)...

I do not get that - why is ***TO*** missing in the first sentence?

Also what is the difference between

> 1a) Having advised many of your colleagues (yet having had no one stand up for me when the shit hit the fan)
>
> 1b) Having advised many of your colleagues (yet having had no one ***to*** stand up for me when the shit hit the fan)
>
> 2a) Having advised many of your colleagues (yet having had no one support me when I faced adversity)
>
> 2b) Having advised many of your colleagues (yet having had no one ***to*** support me when I faced adversity)

What is the difference between 1a and 1b and also 2a and 2b? Are they same or is there any difference? Please tell me what the difference is.

Comment: It's the different usage of 'have' verb. To simply put, 1)to arrange for somebody to do something for you -1a,2a     2) to have somebody available -1b,2b

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you use the verb *to have* like that, you don't need the *to* particle in front of the verb that follows.

Examples:

> The boss wants to **have** me **do** the entire thing all by myself.
>
> It's generally better to **have** your database **do** the necessary data-centric tasks instead of doing all that work on the host language side.
>
> I got no hot water in the shower again. Could you please **have** someone **come over** to take a look?
>
> Hey, buddy, I got a job for you. I'm gonna **have** you **sing** at Mary's wedding reception! I know you like singing.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is between a single instance and an ongoing situation.

For a single event, "I had no one stand up for me" uses "had" as a means to create a passive voice, and is equivalent to "No one stood up for me".

For an ongoing or repeated situation, "I had no one to stand up for me" means "There was no one I could depend on to stand up for me".